# Mongodb lookup with match in aggregate returns an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

This is my **user** document

```
{
   "_id":"02a33b9a-284c-4869-885e-d46981fdd679",
   "context":{
      "email":"someemail@gmail.com",
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Smith",
      "company":[
         "e2467c93-114b-4613-a842-f311a8c537b3"
      ],
   },
}
```

and a **company** document

```
{
   "_id":"e2467c93-114b-4613-a842-f311a8c537b3",
   "context":{
      "name":"Coca Cola",
      "image":"someimage",
   },
};
```

This is my **query** for users

```
let users = await Persons.aggregate(
            [{$project:
            {
                name: {$concat: ['$context.firstName', ' ', '$context.lastName']},
                companyId: {$arrayElemAt: ['$context.company', 0]}}
            },
            {$match: {name: searchRegExp}},
            {$lookup: {from: 'companies', let: {company_id: {$arrayElemAt: ['$context.company', 0]}}, pipeline:
            [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ['$_id', '$$company_id']
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {name: '$context.name'}
                }
            ],
            as: 'company'}}
            ]).toArray()
```

When I run this query I get company field as an empty array, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first pipeline stage `$project` only outputs `_id`, `name` and `companyId` so then when you're trying to refer to `$context.company` in your `$lookup` there will be an empty value. You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) instead:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        name: {
            $concat: [
                "$context.firstName",
                " ",
                "$context.lastName"
            ]
        },
        companyId: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
                "$context.company",
                0
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GbLSug6Wzcg)

Answer (score 1):

When you add field `companyId: {$arrayElemAt: ['$context.company', 0]}}`, then you can use the simple version of `$lookup`. There is no need to set it twice, once as `companyId: ...` and in `let: {company_id: ...}`

```
db.user.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         name: { $concat: ["$context.firstName", " ", "$context.lastName"] },
         companyId: { $arrayElemAt: ["$context.company", 0] } 
      }
   },
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "company",
         localField: "companyId",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "company"
      }
   }
])
```